# What are the Play! module restrictions

Tags: playframework

What are the restrictions and caveats to play! modules. In the documentation the only thing I gather is no application.conf; which is ok; but it seems there is more to it then that. For example if I have dependencies listed in my modules dependencies.yml they don't get imported when running the parent application. Also if I have a job loading in its own data fixtures it doesn't work..? it seems the whole conf folder is what it means perhaps? What am I missing here.

Is there a way to have dependencies within modules? E.g. an Api module with a secure module dependency. And can that module loads its own fixtures?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Modules in Play really are very similar to applications. It's best to think of them as a way of modularizing your application.

A module can have dependencies defined for it in the `dependencies.yml` file and when you execute `play deps` the dependencies get resolved and placed in the `lib/` directory. Then when you execute `play build-module` the entire module (including those jars in the `lib/` directory) get packaged up into a ZIP file and placed in the `dist/` directory.

When you specify a module as a dependency to an application Play takes that ZIP file and includes everything in it into the application. It becomes part of your application and you can use the functionality defined in it.